# Trying to create a clickable button but get thrown error when compiling

Tags: java, swing, jframe, abstract, jbutton

CountingNumbers is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener

is the error i get.

My Code:

```
//Create an application that counts the number of each letter in a given word/phrase
//have a box that has a text box a button and output box

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

 public class CountingNumbers extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {

   public void count()

{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Counting Letters Application");
    JTextField textEntry = new JTextField("enter your word/phrase here", 1);
    JButton count = new JButton("Count Letters");
    count.addActionListener(this);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Color teal = new Color(0, 128, 128);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(teal);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textEntry, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(count, BorderLayout.EAST);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e, JFrame frame) 
   {

       JTextField output = new JTextField("output box", 4);
       frame.getContentPane().add(output, BorderLayout.WEST);
       output.setText("button was clicked");
   }

}
```

I have no clue why this is happening, I am fairly new to java and just learned from a class at my school.

Answer (score 4):

When a class implements an interface, it must implement the methods of that interface *exactly as they are defined in the interface*.  Your class implements ActionListener, and while yes, it has an actionPerformed method, the method signature doesn't quite match that of the interface in that this method is supposed to have only one parameter, the ActionEvent parameter, and your method has 2, an ActionEvent parameter and a JFrame parameter.  Since this changes the method, the compiler will complain that you are not implementing all the methods of the interface.

**Some suggestions:**

- Get rid of the JFrame parameter in your actionPerformed method (see below) so that your actionPerformed method's signature matches that of the interface.
- Make your JFrame variable, frame a class field so that it is visible throughout the class. This way your actionPerformed method doesn't need the parameter.
- Do not re-declare the JFrame in your count method (or the class constructor) but use the class field instead (see below).
- Don't have your class extend JFrame as it is not behaving as a JFrame.
- Fix your code formatting, especially by making your indentation conform to standards.  This will make it much easier for you and for us to understand your code and be better able to debug it.
- Also, don't add a JTextField to the gui each time the button is pushed as I strongly doubt that this is what you want to do... have several JTextFields added if the button is pushed several times.
- Rather, you'll want to make the output JTextField a class field so that it too is visible throughout the application, you'll want to add it to your JFrame, or a container held by the JFrame at the same time that you add your other components to the GUI.  Then you can simply set the text of the JTextField from within the actionPerformed method rather than create a new field.

So not this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e, JFrame frame)
```

but this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

And not this:

```
public class CountingNumbers extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

   public void count() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Counting Letters Application");
      JTextField textEntry = new JTextField("enter your word/phrase here", 1);
```

but this

```
public class CountingNumbers implements ActionListener {
   private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Counting Letters Application");
   private JTextField outputField = new JTextField(10);

   public void count() {
      JTextField textEntry = new JTextField("enter your word/phrase here", 1);

      // add your outputField to the GUI from somewhere in this method
```

Later we can talk about why it's often a bad idea to have your GUI class implement a listener interface, but let's not overwhelm you with too many changes and suggestions at once. :)

Comment: @Cody: see changes to recommendations regarding your output JTextField

Comment: Great answer! I would also recommend making the jframe and jtextfields final.

Comment: @extraneon: thanks! And I second your recommendations.  Myself, I'd make the output component a JLabel or a non-editable JTextField.

Comment: thanks man, that actually helped me out a lot and I got it to work now!

Answer (score 1):

Hovercraft is correct, but I just wanted to add that you might have meant this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
   {
       JTextField output = new JTextField("output box", 4);
       this.getContentPane().add(output, BorderLayout.WEST);
       output.setText("button was clicked");
   }
```

Since your "CountingNumbers" class extends JFrame, it is itself in fact a JFrame. So that's the reason you can call "this.getContentPane()" instead of "frame.getContentPane()". But that's only the case if you want your "CountingNumbers" object to keep adding textfields to itself. If you wanted to add textfields to another frame, you would have to store that frame as a private field of CountingNumbers (which you could initialize during construction):

```
 public class CountingNumbers extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {

   private JFrame frameToAddTextFieldsTo;

   public CountingNumbers(JFrame frameToAddTextFieldsTo){
       this.frameToAddTextFieldsTo = frameToAddTextFiedsTo;
   }

   public void count()

{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Counting Letters Application");
    JTextField textEntry = new JTextField("enter your word/phrase here", 1);
    JButton count = new JButton("Count Letters");
    count.addActionListener(this);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Color teal = new Color(0, 128, 128);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(teal);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textEntry, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(count, BorderLayout.EAST);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
   {

       JTextField output = new JTextField("output box", 4);
       frameToAddTextFieldsTo.getContentPane().add(output, BorderLayout.WEST);
       output.setText("button was clicked");
   }

}
```

Because "CountingNumbers" also implements the interface ActionListener, it is also an ActionListener, so that means it needs to have the same methods as defined in the ActionListener interface. (As previously stated)

Comment: Do you advise the original poster to add a new JTextField to some GUI each time a button is pressed (as is demonstrated in your code above)?  Would it not be better to have the output JTextField as a class field and thus visible throughout the class, and simply call setText(...) on this field from within the actionPerformed method?